# #ifdef in c for filename for guarding static function in header file

Tags: c, header-files

I have a situation in which i have a header file and that has to be included in more than one file. It has some static function prototypes. I want to do something like this

```
#ifdef filename.c 
 static foo(void );
 static bar(int );
#endif
```

Which means if I include this in a file with name filename.c it those function prototypes are active and if included in some other file they are quiet.

Comment: why in the world you want to put static function prototype into header file??? Whats the use of it?? if they are static then use then in the file you defined...no need to declare it in header file.

Answer (score 0):

`filename.c` is a relative uncommon symbol. Apart from that, you would need to explicitly define a symbol in your filename.c-file. Like:

```
#ifdef FILENAME_C_ 
 static foo(void );
 static bar(int );
#endif
```

And in your `filename.c`-file

```
#define FILENAME_C_
```

You should prefer the underscore `_`-version in `FILENAME_C_`, it is more common and easier to read.
Yet, I don't understand why you would declare those functions only? You would need to define them anyway in your filename.c-file. What do you want to achieve with this?

Comment: Unfortunately, the sequence "_ + capital letter" (and a few other sequences starting with an underscore) are *reserved* for the compiler vendor. In user-level programs, it's better to use something like `FILENAME_C`.

Comment: The functions are not written by me but are being generated , and the header file is being included in two c files so I am asking this.